# React doesn't refresh the page in Chrome and Firefox as I compile the index.js file

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React. I have created a project via npx create-react-app my-app. Then I have started the project with the command npm start. When I make changes in the js files in src folder and then save the changes, chrome refreshes the page immediately. But except the index.js file. In index.js file I make changes and press ctrl + s, it compiles but the page doesn't refresh. I had to always manually refresh the page. Does anyone any idea about the problem? Below is my package.jsom file:

"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^0.2.4"

Comment: It seems that is a problem with `react-scripts: 4.x`. Look at this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9984)

Comment: Thank you so much. That is my exact problem and solved now!